# PiSigma: why does 'unfold' bind a variable?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type

I'm trying to understand the paper [ΠΣ: Dependent Types without the Sugar](https://www.andres-loeh.de/PiSigma/PiSigma.pdf) by implementing an interpreter and type checker for the language. In doing so, I've seen that the `unfold t as x -> u` syntax for recursive definitions (syntax is defined in Section 2.1) binds a variable, but I don't see why that's needed. None of the examples in the paper actually use the variable binding -- they all use a shorthand form `unfold t` (meaning `unfold t as x -> x`).

I *do* see that the type checking rule for it (from section 5) uses the variable binding, but I don't understand the implications of this. As far as I can tell `unfold t as x -> u` is entirely equivalent to `let x = unfold t in u`.

Can someone provide an example of when the variable binding is helpful or necessary? Is there some term that type-checks with the long form of `unfold` but not with the short form and `let`?

Comment: I'd quote the type checking rule, but my knowledge LaTeX is too limited. Would some kind editor do that for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any magic/necessary reason. IMO, it's written that way to make it more straightforwardly obvious that `unfold` is an analytic/checking elimination rule; just like why `split` is written the way it is rather than being written as first and second projections, and why `case` is written the way it is rather than being written like `uneither` in Haskell.

Re the "analytic" bit, note how the other elimination rules are either synthetic/inferring (beta) or bidirectional (bang)

Comment: Ah, I see the distinction there. That's a possible reason why `!x` isn't written `force x as y -> y`. Whether or not there's a deeper reason, this answer satisfies my curiosity. Thanks!